# how to get a relative path in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of files , and I try to get a relative path

```
file = "/Users/yves/github/local/workshop/public/uploads/craftwork/image/1/a1d0.jpg"
Rails.public_path => "/Users/yves/github/local/workshop/public"
```

# I am trying to get  => "uploads/craftwork/image/1/a1d0.jpg"

```
file.relative_path_from(Rails.public_path) # is wrong 
# raising :  undefined method `relative_path_from' for #<String  ( file is a String..)

# so I tried to use Pathname class
Pathname.new(file).relative_path_from(Rails.public_path)

# but the I get another error
# undefined method `cleanpath' for String
```

Is relative_path_from deprecated in Rails 3.2 ? if yes , what's the good one now?

Comment: I thought `relative_path_from` was a Ruby method on `Pathname`; wasn't aware Rails added it to String ever (doesn't mean it didn't, but I don't see it anywhere). AFAIK it expects another Pathname, not a string, because it calls `cleanpath` on its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could 'cheat' and just remove the public_path using sub...

```
$ cat foo.rb 
file = "/Users/yves/github/local/workshop/public/uploads/craftwork/image/1/a1d0.jpg"
public_path = "/Users/yves/github/local/workshop/public"
puts file.sub(/^#{public_path}\//, '')

$ ruby foo.rb 
uploads/craftwork/image/1/a1d0.jpg
```

Comment: @Derk-Jan Good point.  I assumed he'd use Rails.root, etc. to make it directory agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Since these properties now return strings, we can convert them back into path names:

```
public_path = Pathname.new( Rails.public_path )
file_path = Pathname.new( file )
```

and then use the relative path function, finally converting it back into a string

```
relative_path = file_path.relative_path_from( public_path ).to_s
```

That together becomes

```
Pathname.new( file ).relative_path_from( Pathname.new( Rails.public_path ) ).to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used:

```
"#{Rails.root}/public/spreadsheets/file_name.xlsx"
```